# iOS Restoration - why is another View displayed before the one I'm restoring?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, state-restoration

My storyboard has: NavigationController -> UIViewController 1 -> UIViewController 2 -> UIViewController 3 -> UITabBarController -> four UIViewControllers (a,b,c,d)

I'm adding restoration support to the app. I've added it to UIViewController #1 and #3 and am now adding it to UIViewController 'c' under the UITabBarController.

When I kill my app using Xcode when it's displaying UIViewController 'c' and then start the app again the viewcontroller's methods are called correctly and the content of its UITextFields are restored correctly.

But in placing breakpoints in 'c' view controller I can see that UIViewController 3 is temporarily displayed. It's viewDidLoad and viewWillAppear: methods are called.

What would typically be the cause of UIViewController #3 being displayed?

I've pressed on implementing restoration for my UIViewControllers and there doesn't appear to be any negative effect from an end-users point of view - without the breakpoints the display doesn't get a chance to update to show the intermediate view.

Comment: Nothing at all to do with my query but instead a query about the minor edit made to this question. Was the expansion of the abbreviation " I'm " to " I am " made because it was felt that those with difficulty reading the English language won't be able to understand the abbreviation?

Comment: Sorry @Giordano-Scalzo I inadvertedly rolled back your minor edit (I was trying most links to find a route to send you a message).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's what view controller restoration *is*. The app launches from scratch; to reach the view controller that was being displayed at termination, the app walks the view controller creation sequence down the chain from the root view controller to the view controller that is to be displayed to the user. It couldn't possibly happen any other way. (After all, if VC2's Back button is to lead to VC1, then VC2 must be above VC1 in the nav controller stack.) And you wouldn't want it *not* to happen, because you might have important work to do as the sequence is reconstructed. By setting breakpoints in the middle of the restoration process, you have revealed "the man behind the curtain". But the user doesn't see that process (it is covered by the launch image), so there's no problem.

In particular it is very important that `viewDidLoad` is called in correct sequence right down the chain of creation, and that this happens for all view controllers before they are sent `decodeRestorableStateWithCoder:`, also in order down the chain.

(However, you should not count on anything having to do with `viewWillAppear:` and its cousins. These may or may not be called and you can't be sure just when. I regard this inconsistency / unpredictability with regard to the timing of `viewWillAppear:` as a bug, but Apple, unfortunately, does not.)